# Volume not really mounted to docker container on IBM Bluemix

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I've created volume with:

```
cf ic volume create VOLNAME
```

And tried to assigned it to container group:

```
cf ic group create --name mygroup --memory 256 --max 1 --desired 1 \
--volume VOLNAME:/usr/src/app/db/ \
--hostname mygreatapp \
registry.ng.bluemix.net/bs/mygreatapp
```

But VOLNAME was not assigned to container group. When I check with `docker inspect containerId`. I see no volumes for container:

```
[{
  "Volumes": {},
  "VolumesRW": {}
}]
```

When I create group from dashboard and assign volume from there, the dashboard shows volume and mount point, but again `docker inspect containerId` claims opposite.

As result I cannot use volume in Bluemix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A storage volume bound to a container group is shared by the containers in the group.  You will not see the volume for an individual container; however, if you inspect the attributes for the container group, you will see the volume associated with the group of containers.

The `cf ic group inspect` command should show something similar to the output below (snipped for relevance and brevity):

```
$> cf ic group inspect myContainerGroup
{
  "Cmd": [],
  "Creation_time": "2015-10-17T20:00:00Z",
  "Env": [
    "sgroup_name=myContainerGroup",
    ...
  ],
  ...
  "Volumes": [
    "VOLNAME:/usr/src/app/db"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With cf ic group inspect I see Volumes, 
"Volumes": ["storage:/usr/src/app/db/:rw"]}
but I don't understand why my data file (sqlite.db) is not preserved between deploys then.

Comment: And there Volumes but no Mounts.

Comment: My testing with a volume for sqlite data did preserve data between container group runs.  I noticed that it took a while after the group was started for the volume to be mounted.  I didn't time it, but it may have been 5 minutes. If you haven't already, I suggest giving it a bit of time after starting the group.  If that still doesn't work, you may want to submit a problem to Bluemix.